# Pointers and multidimensional arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int ia[3][4]; // array of size 3; each element is an array of ints of size 4
int (*p)[4] = ia; // p points to an array of four ints
p = &ia[2]; // p now points to the last element in ia
return 0;
}
```

How does `p` point to the last element in `ia`?

Comment: What exact sort of "how" are you looking for?

Comment: I would think it would point to the first element in the third row. How come I don't have any additional dimension to the initiaziler of ia and yet it points to the last element in the last row, not the first?

Comment: It doesn't point to the last element in the last row. The last element of `ia` is the third row itself.

Comment: The elements of ia are pointers to int[4] arrays. ia has 3 elements. the last one is ia[2]. So the element in your case is not a number, its an array.

Comment: Oh, okay, so by "last element" it doesn't mean ia[2][3], but the third row. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int (*p)[4] = ia; // p points to an array of four
>
> p = &ia[2]; //p now points to the last element in ia

If you have array

`int ia[3][4] = { { 1,2,3,4 },{ 5,6,7,8 },{ 9,10,11,20 } };`

then after `int (*p)[4] = ia;` pointer `p` will be pointing to `{1,2,3,4}` and after `p = &ia[2];`, `p` will be pointing to `{ 9,10,11,20 }`

If you want a pointer to the first element of the last array, from your example:

```
int ia[3][4] = { { 1,2,3,4 },{ 5,6,7,8 },{ 9,10,11,20 } };
int(*p)[4] = ia; // p points to { 1,2,3,4 }
p = &ia[2]; // p points to { 9,10,11,20 }
std::cout << *(p[0]) << std::endl; // 9, because p[0] points to the first int of { 9,10,11,20 }
std::cout << *(p[0]+3) << std::endl; // 20, because p[0]+3 points to the last int of { 9,10,11,20 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> How does `p` point to the last element in `ia`?

`ia` contains 3 elements. Each element is an array of 4 integers. `ia[2]` is the last element i.e. the last array of 4 integers.